# Set a Placeholder if the Value is null in KendoUI

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

The following Kendo grid with a dropdown. The dropdown **AccountCode** item is in form of an object as below;

[image]

The following is used to display the details;

```
    function loadGrid() {

        $("#grdItems").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: itemDS,
            pageable: {
                refresh: false,
                pageSizes: false
            },
            aggregate: [{ field: "Amount", aggregate: "sum" }],
            columns: [ {
                field: "CostCenter",
                title: "Cost Center",
                editor: costCenterDropDownEditor,
                template: "#:CostCenter.Description#"
            }, {
                field: "AccountCode",
                title: "Account Code",
                editor: accountDropDownEditor,
                template: "#AccountCode.AccountDescription#" 
            }, {
                field: "Description",
            }, {
                field: "BillNumber",
                title: "Bill Number",

            },
            {
                field: "Amount",
                format: "{0:n}",
                footerTemplate: "Sum:  #=  kendo.toString(sum, 'n')#"
            },
            { command: [{ name: "edit", text: "MODIFY" }], title: "&nbsp;", width: "120px" }],
            editable: "popup"
        });
    }
```

and it looks like this when displayed;

[image]

How can I insert a placeholder when the dropdown object is empty as shown in the first image? Tried the usual placeholder tag, but it doesn't seem to work.

EDIT: Code added

Comment: Those "Crossed-out" words: _"Midas.<something>"_. Why did you post _screenshots_ of _code_? Just post the code instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure those strings are just javascript code.

```
"#:CostCenter.Description.length > 0 ? CostCenter.Description : 'placeholder'#"
```

Comment: Tried with the edited code and it works. So this means that normal javascript functions can be implemented inside templates :) Good to know